# Incomprehensible behaivior of () -> &str function

Tags: pointers, rust, lifetime

I'm new in rust and don't understand **one moment**:

[Pointer's Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-pointers.html) says: "You don't really should return pointers". I'm okay with that, but in my HelloWorld-like program I tried to return &str. I don't need boxed String, just &str to immediately print it. And I succeeded in this chalenge, but only partially.

So, **question itself**:

Why I **can** do

```
    fn foo(p: &[uint]) -> &str { "STRING" }
```

, but **can't** do

```
    fn foo(p: Vec<uint>) -> &str { "STRING" } //error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
```

, but **still can** do

```
    fn foo(p: Vec<uint>) -> &'static str { "STRING" }
```

What changes fact of switching from slice to Vec?

P.S. Sorry for my dummy english and dummy question. I think, I just don't get a point of rust's borrow-checher

Comment: The "don't return pointers" bit refers to forcing `Box` or other owning pointers upon the caller. When a borrowed pointer works without undue contortions, use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how lifetime specifiers are automatically added:

This:

```
fn foo(p: &[uint]) -> &str { "STRING" }
```

In the past you had to write it explicilty:

```
fn foo<'a>(p: &'a [uint]) -> &'a str { "STRING" }
```

These two are equivalent (but not really accurate since input `p` and returned `str` are not related). It works because `'static` > `'a` so is always valid for any lifetime.

The second example wont work because there is no input reference so no automatic lifetime
parameters are added and the whole thing makes no sense (every reference needs a lifetime, explicit or implicit):

```
fn foo(p: Vec<uint>) -> &str { "STRING" }
```

As you already did you fix it by adding the lifetime to it:

```
fn foo(p: Vec<uint>) -> &'static str { "STRING" }
```